# [Python]: mpi4py parallel numpy dot product

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, mpi4py

So I was trying to parallel the numpy's dot product using mpi4py on a cluster.
The basic idea is to split the first matrix to smaller ones, multiply the smaller ones with the second matrix and the stack the results to one.

[image]

I am facing some issues though the result of the parallel multiplication is different than the one running on one thread except for the first row.

```py
from mpi4py import MPI
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
world = comm.size
rank = comm.Get_rank()
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

a = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))
b = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))

c = np.dot(a, b)

# Parallel Multiplication
if world == 1:
    
    result = np.dot(a, b)

else:
    
    if rank == 0:
        
        a_row = a.shape[0]
    
        if a_row >= world:
            
            split = np.array_split(a, world, axis=0)
            
    else:
        
        split = None
        
    split = comm.scatter(split, root=0)
    
    split = np.dot(split, b)
    
    data = comm.gather(split, root=0)

    if rank == 0:
    
        result = np.vstack(data)

# Compare matrices
if rank == 0:
    
    print("{} - {}".format(result.shape, c.shape))
    
    if np.array_equal(result, c):
        
        print("Multiplication was successful")
    
    else:
        
        print("Multiplication was unsuccessful")
        
        print(result - c)
```

I have tried to execute the split, scatter, gather, vstack commands without the dot product. The gathered stacked matrix was the matrix A. That, probably, means that the gathered indices aren't getting shuffled between the processes. Since I think that it is impossible for the `np.dot` to fail doing the dot product correctly, I guess that my issue is my algorithm. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your algorithm works perfectly. Your problem comes from matrix `b` being different on each process because it is generated randomly on each of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because matrix `b` is generated randomly by the two processors so it's not the same in both. Consider generating `b` in process of rank 0 and then send it to other processors. Replace line:

```
b = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))
```

By

```
if rank == 0:
    b = np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 10))
else:
    b = None

b = comm.bcast(b, root=0)
```